# Bind Single Host to Multple Target Groups in AWS Application Load Balancer (ALB)

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, amazon-alb

I'm using an AWS Application Load Balancer (ALB). I have three target groups listening on three different ports like so:

- Target Group 1 - Port 5672
- Target Group 2 - Port 5673
- Target Group 3 - Port 5674

I want to bind a single host name to all three target groups or ports using any algorithm to select a target group (round robin or whatever):

- foo.example.com Binds to Target Group 1, 2, & 3

How can this be achieved?

Comment: if you want to do any kind of routing why have multiple target groups, why not just a single target group spread across AZ's? If you have a specific routing plan in mind can you specify that?

Comment: I'm using Docker Swarm and have setup a cluster of three RabbitMQ instances, where each has it's own port. I would like to load balance all three instances under a single host name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of target **groups** is that they are targets grouped together.  A given request routes to exactly one target group, and all of the targets that can handle the request need to be in the same target group.